# html redirect to homepage 5 seconds after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am looking to redirect the form submission page back to my home page after 5 seconds. I know there is a way to do this with the meta tag, but this form was created a little different to me. The exact form that i am using is from http://reusableforms.com/d/b/php-contact-form-with-validation-and-recaptcha

any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,
The New Guy

Comment: does the form post to the same page or a plain ( no html ) php script?

Comment: Add a `setTimeout()` in the function `after_form_submitted`.  Also... Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to Create a [mcve]

Comment: @RamRaider The link he posted shows it's an ajax form submission.  It's very clear that there's a function for handling successful posts.  They've just not put any effort in and come here to get an easy answer.

Comment: I never looked at the link

Answer (score 1):

try like this this redirects to home page after successful submission of form

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'handler.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(){
                     setTimeout(function() {
                     window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
                        }, 5000);
        },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 5000);
```

Will work excellent especially if you do your submission with javascript/jquery as well.